# Can't select Cell in UITableView For UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

If you have used Messages application in iOS, you know how we could invoke `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` in any message through edit button and then select each bubble/cell for forward or deletion purpose.

I'm trying to do the same in my application. I can tap on edit and `UITableViewCellAcessoryCheckMark` is shown, but I can't select the cells using it. What more do I need to implement?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details about what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Post updated. Check the image to understand what i'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: Did you set `tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES` ?

Comment: For example in `viewDidLoad`. If the tableview is defined in a nib you can also set it there.

Comment: No not working in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Is the table view in a nib file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16059/discussion-between-martin-r-and-monis-manzoor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a table view as shown in the picture, where one or more cells can be selected with a checkmark symbol, you have to set `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES` on the table view. This can be done either in `viewDidLoad` with

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES
```

or in the Attributes Inspector of the table view in the NIB/Storyboard file by setting "Editing" to "Multiple Selection During Editing".

The `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` method is not needed for this.

(And btw your method returns `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` which is a `UITableViewCellAccessoryType` and not a `UITableViewCellEditingStyle`.)

Comment: Thanks. But without it i am unable to access checkmark style for selecting the cells. What else do i need for it?

Comment: `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` is an iOS 5 feature. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the problem correctly. Does your table look as in your above picture? What happens if you tap on a cell?

Comment: ok, the problem now is that if i don't use UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark in UITableViewCellEditingStyle, i don't get checkmark style option (by default it seems to have delete style). Also, if everything is working fine, selecting the cells is not working even if i enabled it from inspector/code.

Comment: Did you set the allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing option?

Comment: Yes, i did. Still the same result. Can't select the cells :/

Comment: So what happens if you tap on a cell? Does it switch between checked/unchecked ? Or does nothing happen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16074/discussion-between-monis-manzoor-and-martin-r)

Comment: @MonisManzoor: Did you make any progress in this matter?