# Select one cell for UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and other gets automatically unselected

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

once i select a cell in UITableView, i want other cell to be unchecked. Precisely, i want only one cell to be checked for UITableViewCellAcessoryCheckmark in editing mode. How's this possible? I tried doing it through inspector in storyboard and code, but nothing is working.

Any one with a different workaround?

PS: I'm adding the checkmark similar to editing in Messages.app.

Comment: You asked that already in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204492/cant-select-cell-in-uitableview-for-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark/12205885#12205885 and I gave you code in the following chat. You could at least respond to that.

Comment: Yeah, right. But even that solution is not working. So reposted for a refresh query. Let's also continue there.

Comment: hi in didSelect you need to run the loop to unselect all tableViewCell and after that you set the accessary checked current cell then you perform your stuffs ...

Comment: @MartinR That solution you posted has worked. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: .............................................